# Change offset for certain timezone in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

When I launch rake task `rake time:zones:all`

I see

```
...
* UTC +04:00 *
Abu Dhabi
Baku
Moscow
Muscat
St. Petersburg
Tbilisi
Volgograd
Yerevan
...
```

But from 2:00am of 26st of October Moscow time zone has +3 hours offset not +4.

Where this rake task gets offsets in hours for timezones?

How can I fix the offset for Moscow from 4 to 3 hours in my application?